# useState() keep using Shuffle Function React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a Quiz App. Fetching MCQ Data from a `.js` file. I'm using a `ShuffleMcq()` Function to randomize options. React `useState()` Function keeps using that shuffle function. whenever user select an option. Which result in different selected and displayed values. How can I fix this?

**Quiz Page**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import mcqContent from './mcq-content';
import shuffleMcq from '../components/shuffleMcq';

const QuizTakePage = ({match}) =>{
    const mcqData = mcqContent.find(mcqData => mcqData._id === 1);
    const optionsArray = mcqData.m_alternatives;
    const optionsCorrect = mcqData.m_alternatives[0];
    const shuffledArray = shuffleMcq(optionsArray);
    const [option, setOption] = useState();
    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(option);
        checkAnswer(option,optionsCorrect)
    }
    return(
    <>
    <h4>{mcqData.m_title}</h4>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}><div className="radio"><table><tbody>
                  
    {shuffledArray.map((paragraph, key) => (
            <tr key={key}><td><label><input type="radio" name="selected_option" id="selected_option" value={paragraph} onChange={(e)=> setOption(e.target.value)}/>{paragraph}</label></td></tr>
            ))}

    </tbody></table>
    <button type="submit">Check Answer</button>
    </div></form>
    </>
    );
    

};
export default QuizTakePage;
function checkAnswer(optionVar, corr)   {

    if(optionVar==null){  console.log('Select an Answer');    }
    if(optionVar === corr) {   console.log('Answer is Correct');   }
    else{  console.log('Wrong Answer');    }
}
```

**Shuffle Function**

```
const shuffleMcq = function(options) {
    const array = [...options];
        let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
      
        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      
          // Pick a remaining element...
          randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
          currentIndex--;
      
          // And swap it with the current element.
          [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
            array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
        }
      
        return array;
    };

export default shuffleMcq;
```

**MCQ Content**

```
const mcqs = [
    {
        "_id":1,
        "m_title":"Which company is the most valueable in the world?",
        "m_question":"Which company is the most valueable in the world?",
        "m_alternatives":["Apple","Google","Microsoft"],
    },
```

**Current Result**
I selected MICROSOFT as an option `CheckAnswer()` grab this value and return result but it display as I selected APPLE and got result for MICROSOFT. Due to `useState()` keeps using `ShuffleMcq()`  [image: Current Result]
**Expected Result**
This is the expected Result [image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use setOption, file gets hoisted, so it calls the shuffledMcq and data changes. call the function on your required condition to get your result. Here I call the function on mount.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import mcqContent from "./mcq-content";
import shuffleMcq from "./shuffleMcq";

const QuizTakePage = ({ match }) => {
  const mcqData = mcqContent.find((mcqData) => mcqData._id === 1);
  const optionsArray = mcqData.m_alternatives;
  const optionsCorrect = mcqData.m_alternatives[0];
  //   const shuffledArray = shuffleMcq(optionsArray);
  const [option, setOption] = useState("");
  const [shuffledArray, setShuffledArray] = useState([]);
  console.log("ssd");
  useEffect(() => {
    setShuffledArray(shuffleMcq(optionsArray));
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(option);
    checkAnswer(option, optionsCorrect);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h4>{mcqData.m_title}</h4>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="radio">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {shuffledArray.map((paragraph, key) => (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="selected_option"
                        id="selected_option"
                        value={paragraph}
                        onChange={(e) => setOption(e.target.value)}
                      />
                      {paragraph}
                    </label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button type="submit">Check Answer</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default QuizTakePage;
function checkAnswer(optionVar, corr) {
  if (optionVar == null) {
    console.log("Select an Answer");
  }
  if (optionVar === corr) {
    console.log("Answer is Correct");
  } else {
    console.log("Wrong Answer");
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine. But I'm getting this warning `Line 14:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'optionsArray'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: It's nothing. It wants useEffect to have a dependency. But if you only use in mount, you don't have a dependency. If you use it for some other condition, you can use that as dependency.